# Getting Operational Error when trying to migrate Django

Tags: python, sql, django, migration

Whenever I try to migrate my application in Django, the `python manage.py migrate` command throws Operational errors that say:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "main_site_prescription" already exists
```

I tried deleting the table and that didn't work. I tried to `--fake` the migration, but then the database doesn't recognize the change to models.py. This is thrown on the site when I it tries to use one of the columns in a view:

```
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    table main_site_event has no column named initiated_by_id
```

Here are the tables:

```
sqlite> .tables
auth_group                                  
auth_group_permissions                      
auth_permission                             
auth_user                                   
auth_user_groups                            
auth_user_user_permissions                  
django_admin_log                            
django_content_type                         
django_migrations                           
django_session                              
main_site_appointment                       
main_site_doctor                            
main_site_doctor_listOfPatients             
main_site_event                             
main_site_hospital                          
main_site_hospital_listOfDoctors            
main_site_hospital_listOfHospitalAdmins     
main_site_hospital_listOfNurses             
main_site_hospital_listOfPatients           
main_site_hospitaladmin                     
main_site_hospitaladmin_listOfDoctors       
main_site_hospitaladmin_listOfHospitalAdmins
main_site_hospitaladmin_listOfNurses        
main_site_hospitaladmin_listOfPatients      
main_site_message                           
main_site_nurse                             
main_site_nurse_listOfDoctors               
main_site_nurse_listOfPatients              
main_site_patient                           
main_site_patient_prescriptions             
main_site_patient_records                   
main_site_prescription                      
main_site_record
```

and here is the PRAGMA table_info(main_site_event) output...

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(main_site_event);
0|id|integer|1||1
1|activity|text|1||0
2|time|datetime|1||0
sqlite>
```

This is the representation in the model...

```
'''Class representing an event, used for the activity log'''
class Event(models.Model):
    activity = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True) # an action from the list of actions
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # the time of the action in datetime format
    initiated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="initiator") # the user who initiated the action
    target_of = models.ForeignKey(User, default = None, related_name="target", null = True) # the user who is the target of the action
    hospitals = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, default=None, null = True)
    prescriptions = models.ForeignKey(Prescription, default=None, null = True)
```

Which obviously aren't correct (table missing multiple columns)

Comment: Which DB are you using? Could you paste this table here?

Comment: I am using sqlite3. Just updated.

Comment: Is your class fields with SPACES after the ":"??? The way you paste looks like you are not respecting the Python formating

Comment: @Walucas Sorry, just fixed it. Copy paste into stack overflow is kinda screwed up.

Comment: Last question, what version of Django are you using?

Comment: @Walucas Django V1.8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96819/discussion-between-walucas-and-ian).